# getting form value into controller in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a "search" page that have some controls and below is the search page code:

```
<%= form_for :search, :url => { :method => :get, :action => :search } do |f| %>
<table>
      <tr>
         <td align="center" style="vertical-align:top;">
            <h2 style="color:Black; font-size: x-large;">Specs</h2>               
         <table>
            <tr>
               <td align="center">
                  <input type="text" name="tf_Zip" Style="text-align: left;" BackColor="#e5e5e5" Width="180px" ForeColor="Gray" Font-Size="Large">
               </td>
            </tr>             
         </table>
         <table>
            <tr>
               <td>
                  <div class="button">
                    <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search" class="buttonSearch">
                  </div>
               </td>
            </tr>
         </table>
         </td>
         <td align="center" style="vertical-align:top;">
            <h2 style="color:Black; font-size: x-large;">
                    Result
            </h2>
            <% @user_zip.each do |uzr_zip| %>
            <h1><%= uzr_zip.First_Name %></h1>
            <% end %>
            <table id="searchResult" width="100%" runat="server">
                  <tr>
                     <td bgcolor="#CCDBE0">
                        Image:
                     </td>
                     <td bgcolor="#CCDBE0">
                        <%= f.label(:zip, "Mentor") %>
                     </td>
                  </tr>
            </table>
         </td>
      </tr>
</table>
<% end %>
```

And when I am trying to get the textbox value into the controllers page like below

```
def search
    @students=Students.all
    @blah = params[:search][:tf_Zip]
    end     
    render 'search'
end
```

Then it gave me an error below, at this line `@blah = params[:search][:tf_Zip]`

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

Kindle help me. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your params[:search] is nil? 
      so for this you can use

```
   @blah = params[:tf_Zip]
```

or change your input field like this

```
<%= f.text_field :tf_Zip %>
```

or you can use like this

```
<input type="text" name="search[tf_Zip]" Style="text-align: left;" 
     BackColor="#e5e5e5" Width="180px" ForeColor="Gray" Font-Size="Large">
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at your log:  you will see what is coming through in params, then you'll see why `params[:search][:tf_Zip]` doesn't work.

The error is telling you, effectively, that `params[:search]` is nil, and that you can't call `[tf_Zip]` on nil.

Your problem is this line:

```
<input type="text" name="tf_Zip" Style="text-align: left;" BackColor="#e5e5e5" Width="180px" ForeColor="Gray" Font-Size="Large">
```

It will populate `params[:tf_Zip]` because it's name is `"tf_Zip"`.  If you want it to populate `params[:search][:tf_Zip]` then you should set the name attribute to `search[tf_Zip]`.

What would be nicer though is to use the rails form field helpers.  I don't know why you have so much raw html inside a form_for.

```
<input type="text" name="tf_Zip" Style="text-align: left;" BackColor="#e5e5e5" Width="180px" ForeColor="Gray" Font-Size="Large">
```

can be replaced with

```
<%= f.text_field :tf_Zip %>
```

which *will* populate `params[:search][:tf_Zip]`

For the other attributes (Style etc) you should set these with css.  Rails will probably put a class on the field automatically which you can use to do this.  The "style" (note lowercase) attribute can be used instead but it's clumsy as it doesn't allow you to restyle the field (and more generally, your site) with css.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked to see if `params[:search]` is nil?  If it is, then trying to pull `[:tf_Zip]` will cause that error.

Usually you'd submit the form from one controller action and handle the result in another action.

And your statement `end` looks misplaced.

Comment: params[:search] is nill

Comment: You can do traces, for instance, `puts params` to see the elements available to you.  As another answer indicates, you should see `params[:tf_Zip]` does have a value.